# How to change the uitextview font size

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitextview, font-size

can any one help to change the font size in `UITextView`.

```
[textView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:30]];
```

I use this one but it doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i set the fontSize in UITextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054600/how-can-i-set-the-fontsize-in-uitextview)

Comment: Provide more information about your textView

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Have you bind textView with xib or allocated textView?

If yes,

You can use following code to check whether this works

```
[textView setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]];
```

or

```
 [textView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];
```

Comment: This works, but it is really strange that font changing in storyboard has no effect.

Comment: @iMOBDEV I'd add the swift case also, it helped to me ;): textView.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16.0)

Answer (score 62):

Check, if "Selectable" is checked in the xib/Storyboard attribute inspector. If it's not selectable, the size wont be changed

Comment: Please fix this Apple. Making something selectable shouldn't make the font and text justification propagate.

Comment: You are the hero that we deserve.

Comment: Well.. if you use the answer above (@iMOBDEV), then you can leave the Selectable unchecked and it will change the font size while not allowing the user to select the text.

Comment: This seems to be fixed in iOS 10. I had such a hard time figuring out why this was different in iOS 9. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Swift 4.0

```
textField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)
```

Answer (score 10):

```
   UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
   [textView  setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:30]];
   textView.text = @"test my font size";
   [self.view addSubview:textView];
   [textView release];
```

Your code is correct. The problem is from other part of your code. Provide more details about your textView

Set custom font and size in Swift:

```
textView.font = UIFont(name: "ArialMT", size: 20)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
UITextView *myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];  
myTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:14];
```

Comment: Can you give some eplanation with this?

Answer (score 3):

Here is for swift 3.0

```
textview.font = UIFont(name: textview.font.fontName, size: 18)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried it the same way like you with

```
[textView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:kFontName size:kFontSize]];
```

I set the `UITextView` inside `ViewDidLoad`. My problem was, I transformed my view:

```
[_viewEnd setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.0, 0.0)];
```

My problem was solved with setting the properties of the `UITextView` after transforming my `UIView` which includes the `UITextView`.