# TextView's font i not changing in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, uifont

[image]

as you can see in the above i'm trying to change my textView's font , but it didn't changing i searched some related terms on changing for like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19113673/uitextview-setting-font-not-working-with-ios-6-on-xcode-5)

and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517135/how-to-change-the-uitextview-font-size)  , but nothing worked for me

i'm also not sure if this is the correct name of my desired font or not

```
titleTextView.font = UIFont(name: "Myriad-Condensed", size: 25)
```

even in [this](http://iosfonts.com) site they dont have anything related to my desired font  which is `Myriad pro Condensed` according to storyboard's attribute  inspector

anyone faced anything similar to this before ?? or any clue what i should do ? then please let me know

Comment: Are you sure you have installed the font properly?

Comment: @RashwanL installed ? what you mean ? where to install it ?

Comment: For custom fonts installations, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969329/how-to-include-and-use-new-fonts-in-iphone-sdk

Comment: @pedrouan hey man thanks for responding , but your link's question says ***But I dont see it in the font list in Property inspector*** which is not in my case my desired font is there but after selecting that font nothing happening.. , do correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: @remy boys Yes, it was purposely: You say you are using custom font. So first check if your font is embedded correctly and ios renders it. If it is not, it displays default font instead. The link I posted in comment has great answer that explain what to check and set. If your are done, let me know if it doesn't help.

Comment: @pedrouan do i have to check in info.plist ?

Comment: @remy boys Yes, follow that answer, you have to have your fonts typed there. And also, sometimes. Be sure you type correct names, as sometimes, the font your are using has different name as its filename. Try it and send screenshot if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need a font to use. Download any of them in you cass its right here : http://ufonts.com/fonts/myriadpro-cond.html

After downloading drag & drop the font file (otf or ttf) into your project

Make sure you check the box next to your target or the font won’t actually get included in your app (even though it’ll probably show in Interface Builder).

Open up the Info.plist . Add a new array of strings to it: “Fonts provided by application”. Add the filenames for each font you want to use as String entries in the array. (That one ttf file you just added to your project )

Now you're good to go , select that font once again like you did in the attached image.

For more detail see this article https://grokswift.com/custom-fonts/