# How to increase the font size at uitextview

Tags: ios

How to increase the font size at UITextView, programmatically.

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"myfontName" size:20.0f];
```

This code doesn't working.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3055991/1679187

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

**Code:**

```
[_textView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10]];
```

OR

```
[_textView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it like,

```
[textView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold" size:20.0f]]
```

If your not using Attributed string for `UITextView`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this 1 line of code:

```
[textView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"myfontName" size:fontSize]];
```